# Nexus 7 screen.width returns 800 but media query max-width: 720px still applies

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a Google Nexus 7 tablet I'm using for testing some responsive designs. In Javascript, the `screen.width` returns as 800px, as expected (the native resolution).

How come the following media query is picked up by the tablet when the max width of the screen is > 720px?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    .test{ background: red;}
}
```

Comment: Looks right to me - have you tried doing this on a jsfiddle, with no other influences? Does it still apply?

Comment: thos might help you `http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/17586/media-queries-with-identical-width/p1`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Android does target density scaling in order to accommodate the varying screen densities of the Android ecosystem. The Android browser targets a medium screen density by default, trying to emulate the size of elements as if the screen was an MDPI screen.

Using [this website](http://responsejs.com/labs/dimensions/), you can see that the result of this scaling is that `device-width` is `601 px` and `device-height` is `880 px` on the Nexus 7. Therefore, it falls within your `max-width: 720px` declaration and the background appears red.

[image: Screenshot]

`window.screen.width` and `.height` always returns the actual screen size. You have to remember that the **Viewport Size** and the **Screen Size** are two different things altogether.

**If you do not want this behavior, you may add `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` to your `<meta name="viewport">` tag. This will disable the Android target density scaling: `device-width` and `device-height` will report the native screen resolution of the device.**

More information about Android's target density scaling is available in the [Android Developers' Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportDensity).

Comment: I'm a big confused on the nomenclature here... In the `response.js` site above, it lists the JavaScript attributes of `viewport width`, `device width` and `document width`. In css, is the `device-width` media query looking at the JavaScript-equivalent of `viewport width`? Why aren't they called the same thing?

Comment: Support for `target-densitydpi` was removed from Webkit, see http://trac.webkit.org/changeset/119527 and an explanation here: https://petelepage.com/blog/2013/02/viewport-target-densitydpi-support-is-being-deprecated/

Comment: @VolkerE.: New versions (4.4+) of Android are no longer using **Webkit**. Switched over to Google's Webkit fork: [Blink](http://www.chromium.org/blink). `target-densitydpi` is still supported on all Android devices now and for the future. Older versions of Android (4.3 and lower) are using an older version of Webkit with `target-densitydpi` still available.